# group_by posts by day and then date with different div

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following in my `index` action of `posts controller`:

```
@posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
```

In my view like:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.title %>
<% end %>
```

I want to group the posts by day and then the date like the following:

```
Tuesday (date)
Sports
World
Politics

Monday (date)
Sports
Catering
```

I just want to have the day and date in separate div's:

```
 (<div>
    <%= day %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= date %>
  </div>)
```

I am using PostgreSQL.

### UPDATE

### create.js.erb

```
$("#post_table").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('posts/post')) %>")
$modal.modal("hide");
```

### posts_controller:

```
before_action :all_posts, only: [:index, :new, :create]

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.js
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully created post."
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end



 private

    def all_posts
      @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
      @post_groups=@posts.group_by{|post| [post.created_at.wday,post.created_at.to_date]}
    end
```

### index.html.erb

```
<% @post_groups.each do |group,posts| %>
  <% day = group[1].strftime("%A") %>
  <% date = group[1].strftime("#{group[1].day.ordinalize}" " %B " " %Y") %>

  <div class="sort_by_date">
    <span class="sort_by_post_day">
      <%= day %>
    </span>
    <span class="sort_by_post_ordinals">
      <%= date %>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div id="post_table">
    <%= render 'post', posts: @posts %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Update is working fine, but whenever create a new post the refresh part is not working. it refresh but I could see the new post after I reload my website.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

controller

```
  @post_groups=Post.order('created_at DESC').group_by{|post| [post.created_at.wday,post.created_at.to_date]}
```

View

```
    <% @post_groups.each do |group,posts| %>
    <%day=group[1].strftime("%A")%>
    <%date=group[1].to_s%>
    <div>
      <%=day%>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%=date%>
    </div>
    <br>

    <%posts.each do |post|%>
        <div><%=post.title%></div>
    <%end%>
    <hr>
    <% end %>
```

In here I grouped all the posts by weekday and then group them with date.
This will return the `hash` of all the grouped data. hash key will be an array of format
`[weekday,date]` and value for this key will be an array of Posts which comes to this group and i am showing them in view according.
You can fiddle around view to change the styling according to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you Qaisar. Its worked and thanks for the explanations.

Comment: Hi, One more question. when I create or update I got undefined method post. Because, my update action has `@post = Post.find(params[:id]`. So it cant find the `@post_groups`

Comment: Why are you rendering the Index view after Create & Update?
Redirect to Index page after update and create it will again call Index action so everything will be fine.
.

Comment: am using ajax. so create and update js call the index view :-(

Comment: Hi, 
Actually you have applied Before-filter which gives you all the posts-group. but It does not include the latest post which you are creating so it's not included in your result. It will come next time.
,
One quick solution can be to call :all_post after successful creation.

Comment: alternatively you can use after_action

Comment: Thank you Qaisar. I just removed the before_filter. But which one is better to follow? can you give some example of my code. Thank you very much